# Docker - inter-container script execution

Tags: docker

currently my web application is running on a server, where all the services (nginx, php, etc.) are installed directly in the host system. Now I wanted to use docker to separate these different services into specific containers. Nginx and php-fpm are working fine. But in the web application pdfs can be generated, which is done using wkhtmltopdf and as I want to follow the single-service-per-container pattern, I want to add an additional container which houses wkhtmltopdf and takes care of this specific service. 
The problem is: how can I do that? How can I call the wkhtmltopdf binary from the php-fpm container?

One solution is to share the docker.socket, but that is a big security flaw, so I really don‘t like to it.

So, is there any other way to achieve this? And isn‘t this "microservice separation" one of the main purposes/goals of docker?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly call binaries from one container to another.  ("Filesystem isolation" is also a main goal of Docker.)

In this particular case, you might consider "generate a PDF" as an action your service takes and not a separate service in itself, and so executing the binary as a subprocess is a means to an end.  This doesn't even raise any complications since presumably `mkhtmltopdf` isn't a long-running process, you'll launch it once per request and not respond until the subprocess runs to completion.  I'd install or include it in the `Dockerfile` that packages your PHP application, and be architecturally content with that.

Otherwise the main communication between containers is via network I/O and so you'd have to wrap this process in a simple network protocol, probably a minimal HTTP service in your choice of language/framework.  That's probably not worth it for this, but it's how you'd turn this binary into "a separate service" that you'd package and run as a separate container.

Comment: Thanks! But that is a bummer. Maybe I need to change my mind about docker, but, as I said, I thought it is meant to be used in a one-service-per-container manner, so that you can easily switch out/update services, without breaking a complete container.
I guess one other solution would be some kind of docker-in-docker approach, where the main service is run in the host container (php-fpm) and can call the services of subcontainers (wkhtmltopdf, etc.).